# HttpClientBuilder not working

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a code in my java application that connects to a url with a post request and get response. 
The code worked for a long time, and it still does for most people. I have one person that the code works for him most of the times, but sometimes I am getting timeout exception.

The code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/link-to-api");

post.addHeader( "Data1", "my_data" );

HttpResponse response = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_key1","post_data1"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("error: "+ e);
}
```

The exception that I get is:

```
 org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to example.com:80 [example.com/__IP__] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I sniffed the network, and I can see the packets when the connection is ok, but every few minutes, when I get the above exception, I don't even see the attempt connection in the sniffer.

I did ping and traceroute to the server while the timeout is occuring, and both are ok (I get response from the server)

So it seems to me that the problem is in the java application, not even attempting the connection. 
I am using httpclient 4.4.1, if it is of any importance.

Why I am getting these timeouts?

Comment: This is a network error. Java does not discriminate. The problem is not with the `HttpClient`.

Comment: while this issue occurs (the timeout is 30seconds), the internet is working and the domain is working for the computer that has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it . At least in my case, all I did was reset the router on my computer, and the problem disappeared.

I have read on the internet many suggestions to change server's tcp/ip parameters. So if this happens to you, before you do anything, I suggest that you check your hardware as well.